# Django rest framework Logout and Login View don't work

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, logout, django-rest-auth

I'm doing a user registration via email with email confirmation. Then user gets a email letter to activate and finish its registration, login methods works. But I cant logout that user, and log him again. Could you suggest any other methods got logout and login with similar register View.

Here is my RegisterView, that works good.

```py
class RegisterView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        email = request.data.get('email', False)
        password = request.data.get('password', False)
        role = request.data.get('role')
        if email and password and role:
            user = User.objects.filter(email=email)
            if user.exists():
                return JsonResponse('Такой email уже существует', safe=False)
            else:
                temp_data = {
                    'email': email,
                    'password': password,
                    'role': role
                }
                serializer = CreateUserSerializer(data=temp_data)
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                user.is_active = False
                user = serializer.save()
                # user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
                user.set_password(user.password)
                user.save()

                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                print(current_site)
                subject = 'Activate Your MySite Account'
                message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
                    'user': user,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                })
                print(message)
                from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                to_email = serializer.validated_data.get('email')
                email = EmailMessage(
                    subject, message, from_email, to=[to_email],
                )
                print(email)
                email.send()
                # return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')

        else:
            return JsonResponse('Email не указан', safe=False)
```

Here is function for registration activating

```py
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Thank you')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

But my logout and login views dont work

```py
class LogoutView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]

    def post(self, request):
        # django_logout(request)
        request.user.auth_token.delete()

        return Response(status=204)
class LoginView(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,) #условие, если email не подтвержден, не поулчится залогиниться
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        # token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        # return Response({"token": token.key, 'id': token.user.id}, status=200)
        login(request, user)
        return super().post(request, format=None)
```

```py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, trim_whitespace=False)

    def validate(self, data):
        email = data.get('email')
        print(email)
        password = data.get('password')
        if email and password:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                print(email, password)

                user = authenticate(request=self.context.get('request'), email=email, password=password)
                print(user)
            else:
                msg = {
                    'status': False,
                    'detail': 'Email is not found'
                }
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg)

            if not user:
                msg = {
                    'status': False,
                    'detail': 'Эмейлы не совпадают'
                }
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

        else:
            msg = {
                'status': False,
                'detail': 'Email is not found in request'
            }
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

        data['user'] = user
        return data
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What is the error message and the error code?

Comment: @GeorgeBikas when i want to login user, it always returns None user. This error works^ if not user:
                msg = {
                    'status': False,
                    'detail': 'Эмейлы не совпадают'
                }
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')